# Add field to crawled content with StormCrawler (and Elasticsearch)

Tags: elasticsearch, web-crawler, apache-storm, stormcrawler

I have followed the following tutorial for crawling content with stormcrawler and then store it in elasticsearch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTerugU12TY . However, I would like to add to every document the date it was crawled. Can anyone tell me how this can be done?

In general, how can I change the fields of the crawled content?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create an ingest pipeline in Elasticsearch to populate a date field, as described [here](https://kb.objectrocket.com/elasticsearch/how-to-create-a-timestamp-field-for-an-elasticsearch-index-275). Alternatively, you'd have to write a bespoke [parse filter](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/wiki/ParseFilters) to put the date in the metadata and then index it using   *indexer.md.mapping* in the configuration.

It would probably be useful to make this operation simpler, please feel free to open an issue on Github (or even better contribute some code) so that the ES indexer could check the configuration for a field name indicating where to store the current date, e.g. *es.now.field*.